# How to estimate current consumption by ICs

Tags: arduino, current

I'm using an Arduino Due (3.3V) which has a maximum current for all pins 130mA.

How to estimate consumption for a number of ICs?

For an example i use multiple MCP4822 (2channel DAC)

On the datasheet I read "input current" 415-750 μΑ.

But what current the SPI clock signal and the MISO signal consume?

If i connect several ICs does this drains more current?

Does this DAC consumes so small current that i connect as many as i like?

EDIT:
or please only a general guidance: how many ic in general (op-amps, digital pots, transistors) to stay below < 130mA?

About ten or about fifty?

Comment: Read specs again, It will give idle and operating current then add mA for any logic output loads with R. Dynamic current depends on rate of transitions (MHz) and Vcc Output loads add up. so Not so simple but you will get the hang of it.  ARMs and Pics give power specs at end of spec.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Thanks. I try to read it but i can't understand. Does the "input current" refers to VDD or to Vout? Does the "clock" signal and the "Select chip" pin and the SDI pin consume current? Does this adds when several (ic) are connected? Does connecting the Vout pins to a Microphone  input  (for monitoring) drain current? I have made the circuit with 3 mcp4822, a couple of mcp6002 and some digital potentiometer ic and it worked but i get anxious. How to estimate the consumption of current?

Comment: All loads add current.. best to add 100mV shunt series R and measure I . It changes with Vcc and loads and clock speed. learn to Control anxious.

Comment: If you're hoping there's a simple solution to your question, I'm afraid not - it's a pile of work. You have to go around all of your ICs, load resistors - everything - and work out what current they are drawing from supply and driving circuits. This is more difficult with active circuits but their datasheets may list dynamic current to add to static current, as TS has said. This is a 'best estimate' exercise on paper though there is software to do it for you. How accurate must the answer be?

Comment: @TonyM Thanks, for now +-30mA it would be ok

Comment: Also consider a high-capacity digital buss: 32 lines, each 10pF, swinging 5 volts at 100MHz. What is the power? P = F*C*V^2 == 32 * 10^8Hz * 10^-11Farad *5*5 ==32*25 * 10^-3 = 0.6 watts. Your buss driver IC will also dissipate that power internally. What current? F*C*V *32 = 0.12 amps.

Comment: The maximum pin current for the processor is a *limiting* factor that should not be exceeded; the available pin current from all IOs summed can exceed this value.

Comment: @ Peter Smith Can you explain a bit? i.e.  "for the processor" I thought it is the same, aren't all pins connected to the processor?

Comment: Some IO pins might have no load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a circuit with some fictitious ICs, and fictitious currents, that illustrates all the relevant current paths:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffn6nt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is just one giant application of Kirchhoff's current law.

Points E and F are the positive supply pins of the two ICs, the dotted boxes. G and H are the negative supply pins.

V, W, X, Y and Z are inputs or outputs for those ICs. It doesn't matter whether they are and input or an output, all that matters is current direction.

In terms of your question, "input current" would refer to current entering or exiting an input terminal, say X. I know X looks like an output, but current direction does not determine this - it could be an input held low, which would result in that input *sourcing* current, as shown.

Currents I7 and I9 pass straight through their respective IC, and represent what you would call "power supply current", or "operating current" for those ICs.

The key thing to realise is that all the currents entering the circuit from the positve supply voltage source Vs must add up to the same amount as the sum of all currents returning to that source via ground.

All you are concerned with, as far as the power supply is concerned, is that sum total. For each IC or (other path, like Q1) you must calculate the sum of the IC's operating current and the maximum currents sourced by any of its outputs or inputs. The sum of all those sums will be the total, which I call \$I_S\$ here, and this is the total current draw of the circuit from the source \$V_S\$.

To put this in the context of your example, the Arduino will require X current for itself. The DAC will consume Y for itself. The DAC inputs will each sink or source P = 750μΑ. The SPI pins will each sink or source a few microamps, say Q = 10μΑ.

Importantly, if one IC is sourcing current for a signal, whatever else is connected to that signal must be sinking it, and vice versa, so you only need to consider each signal current once. If in doubt, draw the current paths as I have done above, and satisfy yourself of the total currents entering and leaving each IC. You'll quickly "get" it.

So, for this example, with 3 SPI signals, and (say) 2 DAC inputs, the total worst-case current drawn from the supply would be X + Y + 2P + 3Q (I haven't considered sensors here).

It's a bit naive, because you may have 2 or more seprate power supplies sharing some common ground, but again, if in doubt, just draw a block diagram as I did, and see for yourself what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The operational current means complete current consumption of IC. Even if not current consumption on SPI, I2C, etc. is very small, so you can not worry about it. Anyway, 1 IC won't cause power problems on Arduino, so you can connect it and measure current. Also, Arduino's power supply may be not enough for POWERING VCCs, of many ICs. Then you would have to use a separate power source, but it MUST have same ground with Arduino. So, you can't power, for example, Arduino from USB and your ICs' VCCs from a battery.

Comment: Thanks, i have created circuits with two power supplies with shared grounds when I worked with motors. Now I' m interested how big (amount of op-aps, dacs, pots, digi pots ics, some analog multiplexers) i can go when experimenting with arduino due and using just the power (3.3V) provided by the USB and respecting the power regulator of the board and the amount of current allowed by the processor.

Comment: So open data sheet and figure it out.

Comment: You can use the input current value for your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Use LT-spice or any spice-software. But it takes some time to learn this. There are a lot of tutorials online to help you out with that.

Comment: It is very difficult if not impossible to rate current consumption of ICs using spice if you do not have a exhaustive spice model of that IC. And IC manufacturers usually don't provide good models for their products if they are fairly complex.

Comment: True. Still for a major part of the circuit. LT-spice will do fine. For that part it is also accurate. Not all models are available, agree.